Why do some functions/sequences have especially nice geometry and predictable behavior?
Compare those two groups of functions and sequences:

Linear function, quadratic function, exponential function, fibonacci sequence.
Characteristic function of primes, A006577 (Collatz), Recamán's sequence.

Functions in the first group seem to have nice geometry and we know "almost everything" about them. Functions in the second group have less nice geometry (have "holes" which are not easy to predict) and there are great mysteries about them (it's not easy to find new primes, there's a lot of unproven prime conjectures; with Collatz we don't know if all numbers reach 1; with Recaman we don't know if all numbers appear in the sequence).
Why is geometry of the first group of functions much nicer than geometry of the second group of functions? I thought of three ideas which could answer this question, but they all seem incomplete or outright wrong.
Changing inputs
First idea: change the inputs of a function and see how the outputs change.

Linear function ($y = x$: 1, 2, 3...): if you multiply the inputs by A (e.g. 3), the outputs get multiplied by A (3, 6, 9...). Quadratic function ($y = x^2$: 1, 4, 9, 16...): if you multiply the inputs by A (e.g. 3), the outputs get multiplied by $A^2$ (9, 36, 81, 144...). Exponential function ($y = n^x$: 1, 4, 27, 256...): if you multiply the inputs by A (e.g. 3), the outputs get multiplied by $A^x$ (3, 36, 729, 20736...). Fibonacci sequence (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...): if you multiply the input by A (e.g. 3), the outputs get multiplied by A (3, 3, 6, 9, 15, 24...).
Characteristic function of primes: if you multiply the inputs by A, you just collapse the function (because all inputs are now composite). A006577 (1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6...): if you multiply the inputs by 2, it changes the outputs by +1 (2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7...); however, multiplying the inputs by 3 changes the outputs by "+7, +12, +7, +12, +12, -9, +7, +92, +12..." (8, 19, 9, 17, 20, 7, 10, 111, 18...); while multiplying the inputs by 5 changes the outputs by "+5, +10, +5, +18, +10, -3, +5, -3, +18..." (6, 17, 7, 23, 18, 13, 8, 16, 24...).

Functions in the first group have the property (let's call it $P1$) that if you multiply the inputs by A, the outputs change by B.
The problem is that Recamán's sequence has this property too:

Recamán's sequence (1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20): if you multiply the inputs by A (e.g. 3), the outputs get multiplied by A (3, 9, 18, 6, 21, 39, 60).

Maybe $P1$ can work as a test for "niceness" of a function only when a function is always increasing? Or maybe it was a stupid idea in the first place?
Distance between outputs
Second idea: look how the distance between outputs of a function changes (if it does).

Linear function: distance doesn't change. Quadratic function: distance changes by $2n - 1$, by all odd numbers. Exponential function: I don't know, but there has to be some simple rule? Fibonacci sequence: distance between terms is the sequence itself (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...).
Characteristic function of primes and A006577 (1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 16, 3, 19, 6...) don't have consistent distance between terms.

Functions in the first group have the property (let's call it $P2$) of having simple rules describing the distance between outputs.
The problem is that Recamán's sequence has this property too:

Recamán's sequence (1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20): the distance between terms is the sequence of natural numbers (+2, +3, -4, +5, +6, +7).

Maybe $P2$ can work as a test for "niceness" of a function only when a function is always increasing? Or maybe it was a stupid idea in the first place?
Scaling the coordinates
Third idea: a function is "nice" if there's an easily definable set of enough pairs (A, B) such that scaling the coordinates by those factors gives a graph which looks like the original graph. Let's call this property $P3$.

Linear function: you can scale the coordinates by (A, A), e.g. (10, 10) and get the same graph. Quadratic function: you can scale the coordinates by ($A$, $A^2$), e.g. (10, 100) and get the same graph.

But I'm not sure if that adds up. Or if it's even different from the previous ideas.
Context
I'd think a tests for "niceness" of a function/sequence could be interesting to mathematicians. If we could define some test, we could talk about how easy it is to approximate a function by functions which pass the test (that's a very important point: it's OK if the test for "niceness" marks some trivial functions as non-trivial, as long as those false negatives can be easily modeled by functions which do pass the test). I hope that mathematicians have already thought about this, so my question has an answer which doesn't require doing novel research.
(My mathematical level is "high-school math" at best.)

This is a good question, I think. You are right that the functions you listed as nice are nice, and the ones you said are not are not. What they all have in common is that they are smooth. They are in fact analytic. Have you learned what continuity is?.

@Malady, My understanding of continuity is on the level of "you can draw the function in one stroke of the pencil". About analytic functions I googled "a function is analytic if you can choose any finite piece of it and approximate it arbitrarily well by some polynomial" (c.) random Reddit person. Is Fibonacci analytic? If yes, analyticity is probably what I'm looking for.

Because we started with the "easy" ones.  For a headbending not-easy one, check out  Conway's Base13 algorithm.
